# Text getting pushed our of a div when using a border CSS

Tags: css

Im using a div to have a gradient background on a tittle on my weppage.

When using "border" property in CSS the text get pushed out of the div.

I have tried to changue size, take out radius-border etc...

```
#TextKeyboard {
    height: 26px;
    width: 330px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#615bff, #262544);
    /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#615bff, #262544);
    /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#615bff, #262544);
    /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#615bff, #262544);
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
h3 {
    color: #f6b824;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5w7wuay/ here a jsfiddle of my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are predefined styling on some elements, like h3.

To fix your button add this to yout h3 rule:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

---

Edit:

Advice: Use a `reset.css` like you can find [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
it clears every predefined style and gives you the full controll of your styling.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin:0;` to your `h3` class:

```
h3 {
    color: #f6b824;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    margin: 0;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/t5w7wuay/1/